# Version Checking on VBA (excel) code (redhat)

Tags: vba, excel

[image]

Here my example of thing that i will use.

On the left side is the patch it will use `NAME BASE REVISE` to check the version of package.

Can you convert the script here in to `VBA` code. I will study about it and integrate to my real work:

```
if (Patch name = Pack name) then   **** searching for same Name on patch column to reference for patch base and revise number    
       if (base(c column) > base(h column)) ***checknumber[cellbycell] 

           display "yes" in J cell

             or if (base(C column) = base(h column)) then

                    check if revise(D column) > revise(I column)

                      display "yes" in J cell
    else display No
```

So if you can give me  example code ; if you have sometime  please explain to me that what each line of code is meaning.

Comment: This would get you started http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You don't need vba for this

```
=IF($A2=$G2,IF($C2>$H2,"Yes",IF($C2=$H2,IF($D2>$I2,"Yes","No"),"No")),"No")
```

That goes in column J

Comment: Of course I realise that this won't work with the dashes in there at the moment. You would need to do some custom coding (in VBA or formula) to tell excel how to determine how string A is greater than string B. Perhaps split columns on the dashes if you can. Seeing if Column A = Column G isn't an issue, it's only for columns C and H I can see being an issue.

Comment: yes becuase it's like  x.x.x - x.x.x and some time we have to compare with unequal point of number like 2.1.3.1 and 2.13.1 ; excel funtion is not capable of doing this 
(i think it actually can but then i have to split  every single char to each cell to compare it. waste of space)

my bad that i'm not trying to learn VBA before T^T

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub variousconditions()

Dim i As Integer, x As Integer
x = 0
For i = 2 To 10
    With Excel.ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
        If .Cells(i, 1) = .Cells(i, 7) Then '****searching for same Name on patch
            Select Case .Cells(i, 3) '***checknumber[cellbycell]
                    Case Is > .Cells(i, 8)
                            .Cells(i, 10) = "yes"
                    Case Is = .Cells(i, 8)
                            If .Cells(i, 4) > .Cells(i, 9) Then
                                .Cells(i, 10) = "yes"
                            End If
                End Select
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

I have to re-iterate Siddharth's reference as that will tell you where you need to save this code etc. : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Comment: thank you but it still dont work well 

it only show the first  CCC-  but not the other CCC-

 it only show 3 result of yes

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to compare two dot-notation version numbers which you'd need to paste into a new module in the VBA editor.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function VersionCompare(CurrentVersion As Range, _
                               TargetVersion As Range)

    Dim result As Integer
    result = CompareDotStrings(CurrentVersion.Cells(1, 1).Value, _
                               TargetVersion.Cells(1, 1).Value)

    If result = 1 Then
        VersionCompare = True
    Else
        VersionCompare = False
    End If
End Function

Private Function CompareDotStrings(LeftValue As String, _
                                  RightValue As String) _
                                  As Integer

    Dim CompareLeft() As String, CompareRight() As String, CompareLength As Integer

    CompareLeft = Split(LeftValue, ".")
    CompareRight = Split(RightValue, ".")
    CompareLength = UBound(CompareLeft)
    If UBound(CompareRight) < CompareLength Then CompareLength = UBound(CompareRight)

    Dim ElementLeft As Integer, ElementRight As Integer, Comparison As Integer
    Dim ElementNumber As Integer

    For ElementNumber = 0 To CompareLength
        ElementLeft = CInt(CompareLeft(ElementNumber))
        ElementRight = CInt(CompareRight(ElementNumber))
        Comparison = ElementRight - ElementLeft
        If Comparison <> 0 Then
            CompareDotStrings = Sgn(Comparison)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next ElementNumber
    CompareDotStrings = 0
End Function
```

With this you can use `=VersionCompare(H2, C2)` to compare two version numbers and everything else you want to do (like splitting apart the dashed versions) can be done with formulas in the worksheet.

Comment: Jame ! what if it compare between 3 dot and 2 dot. is it okay?........ Like 3.3.10  compare to 3.3.1.2  or do i have to add any line of code


......... Thank You so much for your answer

Comment: You're welcome - It will compare what is available to compare.  So in the example it will compare 3.3.10 with 3.3.1 as there is nothing to compare the 2 with.  You could add code to compare UBounds in the event of a so that in the event of a tie the version with more detail wins.